# Is it possible to get information about what process is spiking CPU for an Azure Monitor alert?

Tags: azure

We have some Azure VMs setup with Azure Monitor alerts that fire when CPU usage goes over a particular percentage threshold.  This is not terribly useful, because when the alert triggers, it sends us an email that that threshold was exceeded, but doesn't include any information about **why** CPU usage on the VM spiked - it just indicates that there was a spike.

We have these alerts going off multiple times a day, almost always for just a minute or two.  My suspicion is that it's something like Windows Defender running a scan, but I can't figure an easy way to really tell that that is what is occurring.

Is it possible to get the alert notifications to include some more information, like a process dump or a snapshot from Task Manager, something of that nature?  As it is, they are borderline useless.

Comment: Hi, did you checked to use a monitoring software, like nagios, pendora, hobbit, etc..  ? as I think they didnt meant to replace a monitoring solution, just meant to be alerted that you need to monitor what happen.

Comment: You setup a function app as an action group for a particular alert type.  The function app can run a powershell script or....whattever you want.   You can have the function app use winrm and kick off a script in the vm that does a dump of processes and various other properties of it's state and have it email the data to you.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-scripts-in-vm